# String concatenation issue with Swift

Tags: iphone, string, swift

I'm attempting to use string concatenation to create a URL for a network call. However, I'm getting intermittent results when trying to concatenate strings.

Attached image shows it concatenates to just `"h"`. Relevant code added below.

Am I missing something?

Thank you.

[image]

```
/* Constants */
private let baseURL    = "https://someurl.com/"
private let URLSuffix  = "anotherString"
private let typeItem   = "item/"

class HITNetworkCoordinator: NSObject {

    class var sharedInstance : HITNetworkCoordinator {
        return _HITNetworkCoordinatorInstance
    }

    func downloadItem (itemID: Int) {
        let taskURLString = baseURL + typeItem + String(itemID) + URLSuffix
        let taskURL = NSURL.URLWithString(taskURLString)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(taskURL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            var responseDict : NSDictionary? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as? NSDictionary
            println(responseDict)
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: I would not always trust the Debugger variable view. Better add `println(taskURLString)` to your code and show the output.

Comment: Yes, the debugger still has some known bugs with swift variables/constants.

Comment: I'll try that. But the network call always fails in these cases, but always succeeds when the debugger shows the correct output.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: No matter what, it's an XCode bug.  I'd file it as such, using your image above.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing this. Could you post a playground example or similar that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this - let taskURLString = "(baseURL) (typeItem) + String(itemID) + (URLSuffix) " and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation seems to get flakier as you increase the number of concat operators (+) in an expression.  I gave up a while ago, and started using evaluators instead. E.g. 
    let taskURLString = "\(baseURL)\(typeItem)\(itemID)\(URLSuffix)"